# Room db crashes app and database becomes empty

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-room, android-workmanager

Very rarely my app crashes with exception pointing to Room DB dao insert method:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
```

When user launches app after crash, its Room database becomes empty and all data is lost. My guess that crash happens because of running background CoroutineWorker (WorkManager).

Crash happens in next steps:

1. User does some action which calls dao insert method in coroutine. Database instance being accessed through singleton DI, which calls getInstance(context) method.
2. At the same time there is scheduled CoroutineWorker running in background, which tries to insert some other data into database. Database instance being accessed by calling getInstance(context) method.
3. App crashes with exception *Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.* Exception points to Room db dao insert method called by user, not CoroutineWorker.
4. User relaunch app and its database becomes empty.

Code for accessing database instance :

```
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "ks_admin").build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
           }
       }
   }
```

I'm not using method database.close() anywhere in my code.

Full stack trace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1232)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:764)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:420)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection (SQLiteSession.java:916)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId (SQLiteSession.java:808)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert (SQLiteStatement.java:88)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert (FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert (EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
arrow_right
-> com.morelavka.app.data.database.dao.TerminalOperationResultDao_Impl$4.call (TerminalOperationResultDao_Impl.java:159)
com.morelavka.app.data.database.dao.TerminalOperationResultDao_Impl$4.call (TerminalOperationResultDao_Impl.java:154)
androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend (CoroutinesRoom.kt:65)
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.kt:106)
androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run (TransactionExecutor.java:47)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:929)
```